# jQuery form .submit() callback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I use an Ajax form i MVC 3. I want to trigger the submit with:

```
$("form").submit();
```

and I want to do a callback function after the form submits successfully, how can I do that?

Comment: How can you do a callback if the page reloads?

Comment: Is the form submitting via Ajax or a standard HTTP POST? Is the goal to show feedback after form action is successfully taken?  Do you need to retain the values of the form?

Comment: the page doesn't reload. It's Ajax. I need do something after the form i succesully posted.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to do it with just client-side/jQuery and retain that state after the submission, because the page gets reloaded.

You're better off setting some kind of a server-side variable once you're in your Action after the form submit.  And then reference that variable in the View when you go to render it again.  Or better yet, have that variable be a property on your Model, which gets set after submit.  Perhaps something like this:

```
public ActionResult(MyModel model)
{
  // Do post-submit stuffs with model.

  model.Submitted = true;

  return View(model);
}
```

And then in the view, you can do something like:

```
<% if (Model.Submitted) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        doPostSubmitStuffs();
    </script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: FYI... this is MVC 2 based.  Not sure if in MVC 3 anything changes - haven't had a chance to play with 3 yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the validate plugin and I include the `submitHandler` option:

```
$("#theForm").validate({    
  submitHandler: function(form) {
               $.post('patient/save',//url
                    { //data },
                    function (data) {
                        //callback function
                    }
              );

    }
});
```

`
Here is the documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: But submitHandler doesn't get called after the form submits successfully.  Isn't it invoked after validation passes, but prior to actual form post?

Comment: Yes, but the callback function is included in `.post()` which I use to send the POST request to the server. In this case, the callback function is invoked _after_ after the POST. See this: http://docs.jquery.com/Post

Comment: Ahh, you know what.. I wasn't even paying attention to what submitHandler was doing inside.  Well, I see your point.  However, Sarzniak never mentioned using AJAX and I assumed standard form posts.  If AJAX is acceptable, then your solution is a valid one (though I'd opt for the $.ajax() way).  Otherwise, if not AJAX, then this won't help him.

Comment: $.post() it's the simple option. $.ajax() it's the more complex one. Anyway, I don't see a valid way to do a callback (in this case) without AJAX

Comment: Yeah, it's more complex, but more robust (e.g. error handling ability).